# Getting "Internal Server Error" when enabling 'Set expires header' in W3 Total Cache

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, apache

As soon as I enable the option

Performance --> Browser cache --> 'Set expires header' to true

I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Then I have to SSH into the server and delete the new entries to make the site work again.

I have googled a lot and it seems nobody has this problem. ANd yes I have already 
sudo a2enmod expires

**Update:**

Here is the log file, your help is appreciated, as I can't find anything on Google.

```
[Wed Jan 11 07:29:35 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 11 07:29:38 2012] [alert] [client xxxxx] /var/www/xxx/wp-content/w3tc/min/.htaccess: ExpiresActive not allowed here
[Wed Jan 11 07:29:42 2012] [alert] [client xxxxx] /var/www/xxx/wp-content/w3tc/min/.htaccess: ExpiresActive not allowed here
[Wed Jan 11 07:33:36 2012] [alert] [client xxxxx] /var/www/xxx/.htaccess: ExpiresActive not allowed here, referer: https://www.xxx.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_browsercache
[Wed Jan 11 07:33:36 2012] [alert] [client xxxxx] /var/www/xxx/.htaccess: ExpiresActive not allowed here
```

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: We Need You (edit your answer and add that) to add the htaccess file so we would have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with issues like this is referring to the manual.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresactive

> Syntax:      ExpiresActive On|Off
>   Context:     server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess
>   Override:    Indexes
>   Status:      Extension
>   Module:      mod_expires

Look at the Context and Override syntax rules. It's OK to use ExpiresActive in an .htaccess file aslong as you AllowOverride Indexes

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause of internal server errors are owner/permission issues. To be of more help can you provide any relevant entries in the apache messages log or the error_log file.

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: It should, but he doesn't have enough rep to comment yet...I'm not sure why the site is setup like that tbh